# *conjunction* vs *implication* or *equivalence*

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently working through a book on set theory and when solving the excercises I had trouble understanding why my solution was wrong. The task was to translate a statement into set theoretic language.

###### 1. "Sets which contain the same elements are equal"

My answer was $$\forall xy(\forall z(z \in x \land z \in y)) \rightarrow x = y$$
while the books answer is $$\forall xy(\forall z(z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y)) \rightarrow x = y$$

###### 2. "No set contains all other sets as elements"

My answer was $$\lnot \exists x(\forall z(\lnot z = x \land z \in x))$$
while the books answer is $$\lnot \exists x(\forall z(\lnot z = x \rightarrow z \in x))$$

I understand why the solutions from the book are correct (as in I can read them and understand that they catch the original statement), however I do not understand why my solution is incorrect.

Could someone maybe explain to me what does my definition include or miss that the correct solution gets right?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. "Your solution differs from the correct one" because $\land$ differs from $\to$ and from $\leftrightarrow$, which should be clear for instance from truth tables. The latter also show you "when a conjunction in difference to an implication or equivalence is used".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that $\land$ and $\rightarrow$ are different. Could you possibly provide an example that illustrates where my solution would be incorrect and the books solution is correct.

Comment: 1) What you wrote means that if two sets contain every set, then they are equal.

Comment: 2) What you wrote means that there is no set such that every set is distinct from it, AND it contains every set as an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone maybe explain to me in what my solution differs from the correct one? What does my solution include or not include that is or isn't included in the correct one?

Lets go over both examples:
$$\forall xy(\forall z( z \in x \wedge z \in y)) \rightarrow x = y$$
In plain english this states that if every $z$ is in both $x$ and $y$ then $x = y$. But what about if $z$ is in neither? Then your statement would be false, and in fact every set would evaluate this to false. $z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y$ says that for every $z$ is in $x$ if and only if $z$ is in $y$, meaning it's true if either $z$ is in both $x$ and $y$ (like yours says) **and also** when $z$ is in neither $x$ nor $y$. For a concrete example, let: $x = y = \{1,2,3\}$, and obviously if $z=1,2,3$ both statements are true, but this isn't all $z$. If $z = 4$ then your statement entirely is false, and then your implication means nothing since it's vacuous, while the books answer is correct.

For problem $2$:

$$\neg \exists x ( \forall z( \neg z = x \wedge z \in x))$$

This is the same problem, but I think the wording is wrong since $\neg \exists x ( \forall z (z \in x))$ is fairly common way of stating it if you ask me.

For a moment, assume $x$ contains every set as an element of itself without thinking too hard, then let $A, B$ be sets such that $A, B \in x$. In your statement,$\neg A = x \wedge A \in x$ cannot be true if $\neg B = x \wedge B \in x$, since $A = B$ and $A \not = B$. You may say that this is a contradiction, but I would say it means that your statement isn't clear. Instead, if we say that:
$$\neg \exists x ( \forall z( \neg z = x \rightarrow z \in x))$$

Then, again if $x$ fits the criteria either $x = \neg A $ or $x = \neg B$ or neither, and then both of the statements can evaluate to true (possibly vacuously), meaning $x$ would fall under our definition of the set that contains every set. The difference is that your statement says there is no set that exists that an impossible statement is true, while the other states that there is no set that exists such that a possible statement is true.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that $∀$ and $∃$ pertain only to sets; i.e. $∀x$ means "for all sets, $x$" and $∃x$ means "for some sets, $x$", and that sets have only sets as elements.

Then, actually...

> Every set ($x$) is the element of a set ($y$): $∀x∃y(x ∈ y)$.

This says that $\{ x \}$ is a set, since one can define it as $\{ x \} = \{ z ∈ y: z = x \}$, so one could take $\{ x \}$, itself, as being the $y$ whose existence was being spoken of.

> Any sets ($x$ and $y$), that have *all* sets ($z$) as their elements, are equal to each other: $∀x∀y(∀z(z ∈ x ∧ z ∈ y) → x = y)$.

This says: there can only be one universal set. These are all equivalent:
$$
∀x∀y(∀z(z ∈ x ∧ z ∈ y) → x = y),\\
∀x∀y(∀z(z ∈ x) ∧ ∀z(z ∈ y) → x = y),\\
∀x∀y(∀z(z ∈ x) → (∀z(z ∈ y) → x = y)),\\
∀x(∀z(z ∈ x) → ∀y(∀z(z ∈ y) → x = y)).
$$

> Any sets ($x$ and $y$), that have the same elements ($z$), are equal to each other: $∀x∀y(∀z(z ∈ x ↔ z ∈ y) → x = y)$.

This says: no two sets have the same elements, and that $x$ and $y$ are just two names for the same set. These are all equivalent:
$$
∀x∀y(∀z(z ∈ x ↔ z ∈ y) → x = y),\\
∀x∀y(∀z((z ∈ x → z ∈ y) ∧ (z ∈ x ← z ∈ y)) → x = y),\\
∀x∀y(∀z(z ∈ x → z ∈ y) ∧ ∀z(z ∈ x ← z ∈ y) → x = y),\\
∀x∀y(x ⊆ y ∧ x ⊇ y → x = y),\\
$$
with the definitions
$$x ⊆ y: ∀z(z ∈ x → z ∈ y),\quad x ⊇ y: ∀z(z ∈ x ← z ∈ y).$$

> No set ($x$) contains all other sets ($z$) as elements: $¬∃x∀z(z ∈ x)$.

This says: there is no universal set.

> No set ($x$) contains all sets ($z$) (including itself) and is different than them all (including itself): $¬∃x∀z(z ≠ x ∧ z ∈ x)$.

This says there is no universal set that also happens to be different than every other set - including itself. That's always true, since no set is different than itself. These are equivalent:
$$
¬∃x∀z(z ≠ x ∧ z ∈ x),\\
¬∃x(∀z(z ≠ x) ∧ ∀z(z ∈ x)).
$$

> No set ($x$) contains all sets ($z$) other than itself as elements: $¬∃x∀z(z ≠ x → z ∈ x)$.

This says: there is no universal-except-me set.

Generally:

> All $A$ are $B$: $∀x(x ∈ A → x ∈ B)$.

> Not all $A$ are $B$: $¬∀x(x ∈ A → x ∈ B)$.

> All $A$ are not $B$: $∀x(x ∈ A → x ∉ B)$.

> Some $A$ are $B$: $∃x(x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B)$.

> No $A$ is $B$: $¬∃x(x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B)$.

> Some $A$ are not $B$: $∃x(x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B)$.